# String Concatenation used in Console.Writeline available outside that context

Tags: c#

This is ok:

```
Console.WriteLine("this is the key that has run: {0}", this.ReportKey.ToString());
```

Is this way of putting together strings only available when building arguments for the console or can it be used in other contexts. Can it be used in the following? I've put my failed attempt.

```
public string RunTheReport(){
    return "Name: " + this.ReportName " key: " + this.ReportKey.ToString();
    //return ("Name: {0} key: {1}", this.ReportName, this.ReportKey.ToString()); <<is there a way to avoid using all the "+" signs?
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx):

```
public string RunTheReport(){
    return string.Format("Name: {0} key: {1}", ReportName, ReportKey);
}
```

Comment: ...can I then also drop the final `ToString()` ?

Comment: @whytheq yes - `string.Format()` returns a string, so you don't need to call `ToString()`

Comment: @whytheq Yeah it will be called automatically, `ToString()` will be called on every (`object`) format parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
string.Format("Name: {0} Key: {1} ..", para1, para2,...);
```

This works with arrays, and can have mixed indices as well

```
string[] sArray = new string[]{"xx","yy","zz"};
string.Format("Index1:{1} Index0:{0} Index2:{2}",sArray);
//Output = "Index0:yy Index1:xx Index2:zz"
```